# ZYNQ-7000 UART issue - no interrupt raised when receiving data from PC

Tags: interrupt, uart, zynq

I'm trying to UART transceiver on my ZYNQ-7000 board using interrupts. Basically, it just take data from the serial terminal and send back to it.

After initialization, a message `Uart Initialization Successful!` is sent to and shown on the terminal which confirms that the ZYNQ can send data to the PC. But whenever I input some random letters, it seems that interrupt handler function, called `void Handler()`, was never called. It seems there is no interrupt generated at all. I've looked up a lot but cannot slove the problem. Could any one please help me with this, please.

Here is my code,

```c
#include "xparameters.h"
#include "xuartps.h"
#include "xil_printf.h"
#include "xscugic.h"
#include "stdio.h"

// serial device ID
#define UART_DEVICE_ID      XPAR_PS7_UART_1_DEVICE_ID
// interrupt ID
#define INTC_DEVICE_ID      XPAR_SCUGIC_SINGLE_DEVICE_ID
// serial port interrupt id
#define UART_INT_IRQ_ID     XPAR_XUARTPS_1_INTR

// interrupt controller driver instance
XScuGic Intc;
// serial port driver instance
XUartPs Uart_Ps;

// data buffer size
#define MAX_LEN 512
u8 ReceivedBuffer[MAX_LEN];

volatile u32 ReceivedByteNum;

XUartPsFormat UartFormat = {
    115200,
    XUARTPS_FORMAT_8_BITS,
    XUARTPS_FORMAT_NO_PARITY,
    XUARTPS_FORMAT_1_STOP_BIT
};

// function declaration
int UartInit(XUartPs *uart_ps);
// interrupt handler
void Handler(void *call_back_ref);
int UartIntrInit(XScuGic *intc, XUartPs *uart_ps);

// main function
int main(void){
    int status;

    // initialize the serial port
    status = UartInit(&Uart_Ps);
    if(status == XST_FAILURE){
        xil_printf("Uart Initialization Failed\r\n");
        return XST_FAILURE;
    }

    // interrupt initialization
    status = UartIntrInit(&Intc, &Uart_Ps);
    if(status == XST_FAILURE){
        xil_printf("Uart Initialization Failed\r\n");
        return XST_FAILURE;
    }
    xil_printf("Uart Initialization Successful!\r\n");

    // main loop
    while (1) {};

    return status;
}

int UartInit(XUartPs *uart_ps){
    int status;
    XUartPs_Config *uart_cfg;

    uart_cfg = XUartPs_LookupConfig(UART_DEVICE_ID);
    if(NULL == uart_cfg) return XST_FAILURE;

    status = XUartPs_CfgInitialize(uart_ps, uart_cfg, uart_cfg->BaseAddress);
    if(status != XST_SUCCESS) return XST_FAILURE;

    // UART self test
    status = XUartPs_SelfTest(uart_ps);
    if(status != XST_SUCCESS) return XST_FAILURE;

    XUartPs_SetOperMode(uart_ps, XUARTPS_OPER_MODE_NORMAL);
    XUartPs_SetDataFormat(uart_ps, &UartFormat);
    XUartPs_SetFifoThreshold(uart_ps, 32);
    XUartPs_SetRecvTimeout(uart_ps, 8);

    return XST_SUCCESS;
};

// UART Interrupt handler service
void Handler(void *call_back_ref){
    xil_printf("Enter INTR\r\n");
    XUartPs *uart_instance_ptr = (XUartPs *) call_back_ref;

    u32 ReceivedCount = 0;

    u32 IsrValue;
    IsrValue = XUartPs_ReadReg(uart_instance_ptr->Config.BaseAddress, XUARTPS_IMR_OFFSET);
    IsrValue &= XUartPs_ReadReg(uart_instance_ptr->Config.BaseAddress, XUARTPS_ISR_OFFSET);

    // if interrupt is asserted
    if( IsrValue & ((u32) XUARTPS_IXR_RXOVR) ){
        XUartPs_WriteReg(uart_instance_ptr->Config.BaseAddress, XUARTPS_ISR_OFFSET, XUARTPS_IXR_RXOVR);

        ReceivedCount = XUartPs_Recv(&Uart_Ps, ReceivedBuffer, MAX_LEN);
        ReceivedByteNum += ReceivedCount;
    }
    else if( IsrValue & ((u32) XUARTPS_IXR_TOUT) ){
        // Rx FIFO timeout / idle
        XUartPs_WriteReg(uart_instance_ptr->Config.BaseAddress, XUARTPS_ISR_OFFSET, XUARTPS_IXR_TOUT);
        ReceivedCount = XUartPs_Recv(&Uart_Ps, ReceivedBuffer, MAX_LEN);
        ReceivedByteNum += ReceivedCount;

        // send out
        for(u32 sendByte=0;sendByte<ReceivedByteNum;sendByte++){
            XUartPs_SendByte(XPAR_PS7_UART_1_BASEADDR, ReceivedBuffer[sendByte]);
        }
        ReceivedByteNum = 0;
    }
}

// UART Interrupt init
int UartIntrInit(XScuGic *intc, XUartPs *uart_ps){
    int status;

    // initialize the interrupt controller
    XScuGic_Config *intc_cfg;
    intc_cfg = XScuGic_LookupConfig(INTC_DEVICE_ID);
    if(NULL == intc_cfg) return XST_FAILURE;

    status = XScuGic_CfgInitialize(intc, intc_cfg, intc_cfg->CpuBaseAddress);
    if(status != XST_SUCCESS) return XST_FAILURE;

    // set and enable interrupt exception handle function
    Xil_ExceptionInit();
    Xil_ExceptionRegisterHandler(XIL_EXCEPTION_ID_INT,
        (Xil_ExceptionHandler) XScuGic_InterruptHandler, (void *) intc);

    // set interrupt handler for interrupt
    XScuGic_Connect(intc, UART_INT_IRQ_ID, (Xil_ExceptionHandler) Handler, (void *) uart_ps);

    // set interrupt trigger mode
    XUartPs_SetInterruptMask(uart_ps, XUARTPS_IXR_RXOVR | XUARTPS_IXR_TOUT);

    Xil_ExceptionEnable();
    XScuGic_Enable(intc, UART_INT_IRQ_ID);

    return XST_SUCCESS;
}
```

I'm using UART1 controller at MIO 48, 49 which is confirmed at both the Vivado and the schematic.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few problems of your program.

### Receive function

It seems you have not called the UART receive function (XUartPs_Recv).
In interrupt mode, the UART controller will start receiving after you called XUartPs_Recv, this function is non-blocking. When all data received, the UART controller will generate an interrupt, and all data has been written to the receive buffer by the interrupt handler function.

```
XUartPs_Recv(uart_ps, RecvBuffer, SIZE_IN_BYTE);
```

### Interrupt Handler

UARTPS library provided the interrupt handler function (XUartPs_InterruptHandler). So you need to bind it to the XScuGic

```
XScuGic_Connect(intc, UART_INT_IRQ_ID,
    (XInterruptHandler) XUartPs_InterruptHandler, uart_ps);
```

This interrupt handler can help you receive the data from UART FIFO and write to the receive buffer.

### Custom Callback

If you want to do something when the interrupt occoured, you don't need to write a new handler function by yourself, but a Callback function is needed.

```
XUartPs_SetHandler(uart_ps, (XUartPs_Handler)Handler, uart_ps);
```

Use this function, your custom handler will be called from the
interrupt context (XUartPs_InterruptHandler) when data has been sent or received.

### Addition

You may set the receiver timeout. If it is not set, and the last few bytes of data do not trigger the over-water or full interrupt, the bytes will not be received. By default it is disabled.

```
XUartPs_SetRecvTimeout(uart_ps, 8);
```

### Reference

Please refer the [official example by Xilinx on GitHub](https://github.com/Xilinx/embeddedsw/blob/master/XilinxProcessorIPLib/drivers/uartps/examples/xuartps_intr_example.c).